# javascript When I try to use a array ,it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, axios

When I use the second array,it shows undefined,but I can use the first array.

```
this.$axios.get("/classes/")
  .then(response => {
    this.tableData = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      this.cName.push(response.data[i].className);
    }
    for (var ii = 0; ii < response.data.length; ii++) {
      this.$axios.get("/classStudent/?className=" + this.cName[ii])
        .then(response => {
          this.cPeoplecount.push(String(response.data.length));
        })
    }
  })
```

the first array is cName,the second array is cPeoplecount.

[image: console log]

Comment: Where did you define `this.cPeoplecount`?

Answer (score 0):

i guess all your code is inside a function then this should be a [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to do asynchronous using `await` on every axios request, as below:

```
async myFunction () {
  ...
  for (var ii = 0; ii < response.data.length; ii++) {
      await this.$axios.get() ...
  }
  ...
}
```